# Manual Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

In one of the scenarios I have, there is need to do remote validation to make sure a field is not entered again.

This could be done using the ASP.NET MVC 3 Remote Validation, however, this works perfect in a form that is used to **CREATE** a record, not in a form that is used to **EDIT** a record, or else, it will always give me an error that the record is already present.

So what I need for this Edit form is send Id/Name columns to validate the existence of another record with the same name, in other words, do I have any other record 'other than the one with ID' that has the same "Name"?

The server-side logic working perfect, the problem is with jQuery in displaying the error inside the jQuery UI dialog. I followed the same way used by jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js.

On the View itself, I am running the following:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        RemoteValidate({
            formName: "CultureEditForm",
            inputName: "Name",
            inputId: "CultureId",
            url: "/Culture/CultureEditNameExists",
            dupTmpl: "dupTmpl"
        });
    });
```

The RemoteValidate() function as follows:

```
RemoteValidate = function (options) {    
    $('#' + options.formName + ' input[name=\"' + options.inputName + '\"]').live('blur', function () {
        var params = {
            name: $('#' + options.formName + ' input[name=\"' + options.inputName + '\"]').val(),
            id: $('#' + options.formName + ' input[id$=\"' + options.inputId + '\"]').val()
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: options.url,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(params, null, 2),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (!response) {
                    _onError(options.formName, options.inputName);
                }
                else {
                    _onSuccess(options.formName, options.inputName);
                }
            }
        });        
    });

    function _onError(formId, inputElement) {
        var container = $('#' + formId).find("[data-valmsg-for='" + inputElement + "']"),
            replace = $.parseJSON(container.attr("data-valmsg-replace")) !== false;

        container.removeClass("field-validation-valid").addClass("field-validation-error");

        if (replace) {
            container.empty();
            $('Name already exists').appendTo(container);
        }
    }

    function _onSuccess(formId, inputElement) {
        var container = $('#' + formId).find("[data-valmsg-for='" + inputElement + "']"),
            replace = $.parseJSON(container.attr("data-valmsg-replace"));

        if (container) {
            container.addClass("field-validation-valid").removeClass("field-validation-error");

            if (replace) {
                container.empty();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As long as the dialog window is open, I keep on trying values, and it works "shows/hide" error message.

However, when I close dialog, then click on another record to edit, it opens the dialog again with new values, however, when it tries to send server a request to check if a record exists in database, **IT'S SENDING THE DATA OF THE PREVIOUS RECORD THAT WAS BEING EDITED**

I've made bold the line above that prepares the object to be sent to server.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with dynamic Views or any other HTML content is always considered a special case and sensitive. I had to change the way I am accessing data fields inside the event handler for it to work.

As it seems, jQuery was always reading the old values of the first HTML View that was loaded. To make it dynamic and read data related to the View being displayed, I had to write the following:

```
        $('.rm-field').live('blur', function () {
        if ($(this).next()) {
            var params = {
                name: $(this).val(), id: $('input:last-child', $(this).parents('form')).val()
            }

            var element = $(this);
            var container = $(this).next();
            var url = element.parents('form').attr('data-rm-url');

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(params, null, 2),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (!response) {
                        if (container) {
                            container.removeClass("field-validation-valid").addClass("field-validation-error");
                            container.empty();
                            $('Name already exists').appendTo(container);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (container) {
                            container.addClass("field-validation-valid").removeClass("field-validation-error");
                            container.empty();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I had to add a **class .rm-field** to every input field, then attached to it the **blur event**, after that I was able to grab the value of the input field.

I also needed to access the hidden field **cultureId** but jQuery kept accessing the first View HTML, so that was no good. What I did instead is I used the **parents()** navigation selector, to reach the **form** then grab the last child which is in my case the hidden field holding the ID of the record being edited.

After that, simple DOM manipulation to add/remove the error message.

HTH,
Regards